# (python) pyusb can get the idVendor, idProduct but dev is none

Tags: python, pyusb

I'm facing that for python pyusb **can get the idVendor, idProduct successfully but my dev is still none**, which will affect my later operation, I need a hand for here, thanks.

mostly the pyusb read and write function is working, so I am worndering.

the code

```
import time
from usb.core import find
from usb.util import get_string
import usb.backend.libusb1
import re
import usb.core
import usb.util
import os
import numpy as np

def info_usb_device(dev):
    xdev = find(idVendor=dev.idVendor, idProduct=dev.idProduct)
    if xdev.bDeviceClass == 9: 
        return
    if xdev._manufacturer is None:
        xdev._manufacturer = get_string(xdev, xdev.iManufacturer, langid=1033)
    if xdev._product is None:
        xdev._product = get_string(xdev, xdev.iProduct, langid=1033)
    device_info = '[%20s] %8d %9d %s - %s' % (xdev.serial_number, dev.idVendor, dev.idProduct,
                                 str(xdev._manufacturer).strip(),
                                 str(xdev._product).strip())
    return xdev.serial_number, device_info 


def add_usb_devices(device_dict):
    new_devices = []
    for bus in usb.busses():
        for dev in bus.devices:
            if dev is None:
                continue
            serial_info = info_usb_device(dev)
            if serial_info is not None:
                (serial, info) = serial_info
                if serial not in device_dict:
                    new_devices.append(serial)
                    device_dict[serial] = info
    return new_devices


if __name__ == "__main__":
    device_dict = {}
    print('%22s %8s %9s %s' % ('serial', 'idVendor', 'idProduct', 'Manufacturer - Product'))
    print('-'*22, '-'*8,  '-'*9, '-'*30)
    # first scan
    add_usb_devices(device_dict)
    for device_info in device_dict.values():
        print(device_info)
    # next scans
    for i in range(5):  # run 5 more scans 
        new_serials = add_usb_devices(device_dict)
        if len(new_serials) > 0:
           print('** (scan %d) FOUND NEW USB DEVICES/SERIALS: %s' % (i, new_serials))
           for serial in new_serials:
               print(device_dict[serial])
        time.sleep(3)  # waiting 3 seconds before new scan

    str_device_dict_serial = device_dict[serial]
    listed__device_dict_serial = re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', str_device_dict_serial)


    print('Scans completed.')

    print("+ + + + + + + + + + + + +")
    print(device_dict[serial])
    print(listed__device_dict_serial)



input_idVendor = listed__device_dict_serial[0]
input_idProduct = listed__device_dict_serial[1]

dev = usb.core.find(idVendor= input_idVendor, idProduct=input_idProduct)



print(input_idVendor)
print(input_idProduct)

print(dev)
#print(ep)
```

and the output:

```
(base) joy@joy-System-Product-Name:~$ sudo python '/home/joy/fe_dir/combined_function.py'
                serial idVendor idProduct Manufacturer - Product
---------------------- -------- --------- ------------------------------
[                None]     1133     49271 Logitech - USB Optical Mouse
[             2004888]     1423     37728  - USB Reader
[5334354E373539325A315A4B]     5117      2112 Generic - External
** (scan 2) FOUND NEW USB DEVICES/SERIALS: ['01DZTW5EXY5TSUF8']
[    01DZTW5EXY5TSUF8]    34148      4096 JetFlash - Mass Storage Device
Scans completed.
+ + + + + + + + + + + + +
[    01DZTW5EXY5TSUF8]    34148      4096 JetFlash - Mass Storage Device
['34148', '4096']
34148
4096
None
```

the bottom's "None" showing that somehow I couldn't get the dev

Comment: Please always add a link to related posts, like your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73939537/5730279) where the given code originates from.

Answer (score 2):

#### See example in PyUSB docs

Please read the docs. The `find` function requires **numerical arguments** for parameters `idVendor` and `idProduct`, not strings.

See [example in docs](https://github.com/pyusb/pyusb/blob/master/docs/tutorial.rst#lets-get-it-started)

```
# find our device
dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=0xfffe, idProduct=0x0001)
```

#### Fix by conversion to number

The numbers can be either specified in hexadecimal format like `0x0001` or in decimal `1`.

Here, your regex-search returns strings. So you need to convert those strings to numbers, e.g. using [`int(str)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int):

```
device_formatted_str = device_dict[serial]
(idVendor, idProduct, *_) = re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', device_formatted_str)  # unpack tuple into 2 required arguments. Remainder neglected.
print(type(idVendor), idVendor, type(idProduct), idProduct)  # debug print types and values
dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=int(idVendor), idProduct=int(idProduct))  # convert string to number, here int
print(dev)
```

See also:

- Tutorial on unpacking: [Python - Unpack Tuples](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_tuples_unpack.asp)